# nodejs + mongoose - get the document size without querying all its content?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bson

Is it possible to get a document size before updating or adding data into it?

I am using this package to count a doc size:

```
// Get BSON parser class.
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson
var bson = require("bson");
// Create a bson parser instance.
var BSON = new bson();
```

And this is my example code:

```
var docSize = 0;
Piece.findOne({
   _id: lastPiece._id
}, function(err, piece) {

    // Get the document size.
    docSize = BSON.calculateObjectSize(piece);
    // do something.
})
.select("-data");
```

But the docSize I get in there is **not** correct because I **single out** `data` from the query. `data` is the field that takes up lots of doc size, and that I don't want to query it becos I don't need it in certain cases, like this above.

So is there anyway to know a doc size without querying the content of a doc?

Comment: Are you interested in the size of a random doc or average object size in the collection. `db.collection.stats()` returns you `avgObjSize`

Comment: @hyades i just want to make sure my doc size is not over 16MB before adding new data into it. I am using mongoose, how can i use `db.collection.stats()` in mongoose?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @JoshJ nope I am afraid...